# Http to https redirect issue

Tags: bamboo

Our Bamboo application hosted on AWS ec2 instance and frontend configuration as a classic load balancer. Recently we upgraded the from ubuntu 14 to ubuntu 18 with higher bamboo version(7.0.4) after that does not work HTTP to https redirect.

Could you please help me with this matter?

**Server xml configuration:**

```
 <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="10" minSpareThreads="5" port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" proxyName="example.com" proxyPort="80" redirectPort="443" scheme="http" secure="false" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>
    <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" proxyName="example.com" proxyPort="443" scheme="https" secure="true" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"/>
```

**LB setting:**

[image]

Regards,
Nataraj.R

Comment: If you've made changes to the server this will be the first step to investigate first. Classic load balancer redirects are sourced the the instance :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams : In normally, I can able to access an application with https protocol. but if I access the HTTP protocol, it doesn't redirect properly

Comment: I understand, what do you mean by doesn't redirect properly? What kind of behaviour are you experiencing :)

Comment: classic load balancer does not support redirect rule by default, also TCP port integrated protocol for agent communication that was reason we haven't choose the application load balancer.

Comment: I want to redirect Http to https request if someone accesses the application with Http

Comment: Yes I understand this, so is the behaviour that its not or that its getting caught in a loop? Did you upgrade the bamboo version too?

Comment: Yes, we upgraded the bamboo version.

Comment: There is likely a change in behaviour for this, you're probably best of with investigating this direction first :)

Comment: ok Sure, let me degrade the bamboo version

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.

A Older tomcat version contains value(http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee). but the latest tomcat version contains with http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee. because of that our ansible script skipped.

```
- name: Adapt {{ path }}/atlassian-bamboo/WEB-INF/web.xml
  xml:
    path: "{{ path }}/atlassian-bamboo/WEB-INF/web.xml"
    namespaces:
      x: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    xpath: "/x:web-app"
    input_type: yaml
    add_children: "{{ bamboo_configuration_webapp_additions }}"
    pretty_print: True
    state: present
  changed_when: False
```

We added the below value to the web.xml file under tomcat location.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Bamboo</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```